# Is there a way to create a function that will run this code but without passing so many arguments?

Tags: python, optimization, coding-efficiency

I am trying to make code from my project more efficient, shorter but not hard to read/understand.

I see that there are some actions that repeat themselves a couple of times in the code. It is a game so it is required to repeat those.
I thought that maybe I should create a function to call every time instead, but it does not seem friendly to read, because, following a condition, I need to change a couple of variables so I need to pass all of them to the function.

Here is an example:

```
if nxtTurn == 'player1':
    card2, player1 = EgyptionWarHelper.pull_out_card(player1, nxtTurn)
    storage.append(card2)
    nxtTurn = 'player2'
else:
    card2, player2 = EgyptionWarHelper.pull_out_card(player2, nxtTurn)
    storage.append(card2)
    nxtTurn = 'player1'
```

I wanted to create a function that does this, but then realized I will need to pass all of the variables to it and then return a tuple of 2 variables at the end of it. I did hear about global variables but I never really used them and I don't know if they are the solution for this.

**EDIT: I found out that I didn't have to pass some of the argument so after I edit the function and used temporary variables as well, the code is much more readable.**

**Additionally, as commented, I didn't have to return `player` and `player2` because python passes lists by reference and not by value.**

Comment: Why do you pass the player into `pull_out_card` and also return it from there?

Comment: @TomDalton Honestly now when I look at it I don't think I need to.I remove an element from that list with `pull_out_card` so I don't have to return it right?Edit:I'm not sure because the function is from the script `EgyptionWarHelper` and it is my first time using a script.

Comment: `player1` and `player2` are lists

Comment: You should make it a class, and make all the variables attributes. Then you wouldn't need to pass all the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not using a temporary variable ?

```html
if nxtTurn == 'player1':
    player = player1
    nxtTurn = 'player2'
else:
    player = player2
    nxtTurn = 'player1'
  
card2, player1 = EgyptionWarHelper.pull_out_card(player, nxtTurn)
storage.append(card2)
```

it's easily readable and maintainable.

Comment: Now I understood what you meant.It does make it shorter and more readable but I want to create a function,so I will short the code much more.I guess I will just create a function,I realized I don't have to return the lists,so I just need to pass 2 variables to the function.